# MySQL DELETE statement doesn't use index although the same SELECT query does

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, delete, explain, query-performance

I've got a table with ~30 million rows (and soon twice/triple times more) where I have to do quite regular updates. The table structure is like the following:

```
id, 
cookie_id VARCHAR(45), 
country VARCHAR(45), 
category VARCHAR(45), 
other_non_relevant_columns
```

Indexes look like this:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM data;
+-------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| data  |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id          | A         |    24767570 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| data  |          1 | cookie_index           |            1 | cookie_id   | A         |    14440214 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| data  |          1 | country_category_index |            1 | country     | A         |         498 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| data  |          1 | country_category_index |            2 | category    | A         |         997 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So there's a non-unique index on cookie_id, and non-unique index on country+category columns. Now the case is, every week I should run query to

1. Delete all data belonging to country='Y' AND category='X' (5 to 20 million rows)
2. Import fresh data (similar amount)

The problem is, deleting the data takes crazy amount of time - that's why I've set up an index on country+category columns. However, 'DELETE' statement still doesn't use the index and instead tries to scan the whole table:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN DELETE FROM data WHERE country='Y' and category='X';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys          | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | data  | NULL       | ALL  | country_category_index | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 24767570 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Select works fine:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT id, cookie_id FROM data WHERE country='Y' and category='X';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys          | key                    | key_len | ref         | rows     | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data  | NULL       | ref  | country_category_index | country_category_index | 365     | const,const | 10130630 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Is there any way to optimize DELETE query?

Comment: DELETE works with the table anycase, whereas SELECT - only when it builds output recordset.

Comment: Have you considered partitioning?

Comment: Did you find the reason and solution in the end? I have the same issue and none of the ideas here give any solution.
Actually since you have `id` column I suppose you can do batches. I don't have such a luxury.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose if you try to run "EXPLAIN SELECT *" instead of "SELECT id, cookie_id" then server will prefer to use table scan too because execution plan with index seek will require a lot (millions) of key lookups. The same consideration works for DELETE statement. So delete with table scan should be the fastest non-partitioned solution. If you want to reduce duration of locking periods you can use batches as suggested in @anisakras answer.

Comment: I get similar behavior to the question, even if I do an `explain select *`. Assuming that by doing in batches you mean adding a limit clause, that doesn't help, it still doesn't use an index.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting in batches? Maybe the SQL optimizer thinks that the FULL DELETE is too big so it's not using an index, instead it accesses the full table.. Try spitting in 5-10 batches, I think the explain delete will be different then

Comment: More tips on chunking up a delete:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 0):

By deleting the data first, you are essentially making the data inaccessible.  Don't you want to avoid this "downtime"?

Consider loading the replacement data into a temp table, then doing IODKU to update the main data:

```
INSERT INTO main (...)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
             col1 = VALUES(col1),
             ...
    SELECT ... FROM temp;
```

If there could be rows to remove; IODKU won't provide that feature.  However, you could precede it with something like

```
ALTER TABLE temp ADD INDEX (...);  -- to speed up the LEFT JOIN below

DELETE FROM main
       USING main
        LEFT JOIN temp ON ...
       WHERE temp... IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try like this:
`EXPLAIN DELETE d.* FROM data d WHERE country='Y' and category='X'`